# Increment TextView with button click

Tags: android

thanks for the help but I'm still struggling. I did this:

**Button in xml:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:onClick="incrementScore"
    android:text="@string/player" />
```

**Code in main (right at the end):**

*WhenI press the button the app crashes. Where specifically should I put this code?*

```
Context context;    
TextView tv;
Button incrementer;

public void incrementScore(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    incrementer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    context=this;

    incrementer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String present_value_string = tv.getText().toString();
            int present_value_int = Integer.parseInt(present_value_string);
            present_value_int++;

            tv.setText(String.valueOf(present_value_int));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: give us your error log to see what kind of error you had.

Answer (score 1):

In your class create:

```
       int score = 0;
```

And then;

```
       button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // score operation like score += increment_value;
                t1.setText(""+score);
            }
        });
```

If you need to "save" the score ocne you quit the application, you need to use SharedPreferences to show/update the value.

Answer (score 0):

I cant actually figure out what the increment textview means ....

May be adding more textviews or increasing the value inside the textview. I will go with later.

```
Context context;
TextView tv;
Button increamenter;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
   tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   incrementer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    context=this;

   incrementer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        try
        {
            String presentValStr=tv.getText().toString();
            int presentIntVal=Integer.parseInt(presentValStr);
            presentIntVal++;
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(presentIntVal));
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(context,"Some error :(",2000).show();
         }
   });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Initialize a value in class first

```
Context context;    
TextView tv;
Button incrementer;
int value = 0;
```

> Convert int value to String after incrementation

```
incrementer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        value++;
        String num = String.valueOf(value);
        tvText.setText(num);
    }
});
```