# Increment TextView with Button click and JSON

Tags: java, android, json, button, textview

Ok , so i want to increment some TextView who shows datas from a JSON Code.

```
package com.example.kane.bibliokane;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import static android.R.attr.data;


public class ListesLivres extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView Titre, Auteur, Categorie , Editeur , Prix;
int score = 0;
Button b1,b2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listeslivres);

    Titre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    Auteur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
    Categorie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
    Editeur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
    Prix = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    new getData().execute();
}

class getData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.43.13:8000/api/liste.json");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }


        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String t = jsonObject.getString("titre");
            String a = jsonObject.getString("auteur");
            String c = jsonObject.getString("categorie");
            String e = jsonObject.getString("editeur");
            String p = jsonObject.getString("prix");
            Titre.setText(t);
            Auteur.setText(a);
            Categorie.setText(c);
            Editeur.setText(e);
            Prix.setText(p);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

I saw how to increment TextView via a Button in this topic : [Increment TextView with button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254901/increment-textview-with-button-click)

But i don't know how to adapt it with my code , since i want the program to show first , datas from jsonObject (0) , then if i click in a button (b1) , it increment ++ , and in another button (b2) , it decrement -- until it reach 0 .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) you need to make `jsonArray` variable global. and also define a variable `int currentIndex` to keep track of the current index shown
2) Attach an onclick listener to button to modify the index;

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListner(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        currentIndex++;
        updateTextViews();
    }
});
```

`b2` will have a similar listener for decrementing

3) Define a method which uses `currentIndex` and `jsonArray` and sets the value of the TextViews based on it

```
public void updateTextViews(){
   //Add checks for current index to ensure it lies within range
   try{
      JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(currentIndex);
      //Set content for textviews
   }catch(JSONException e){

   }
}
```